# connectedCheck/connectedInstrumentTest am instrument parameter

Tags: java, android, gradle, instrumentation

Is it possible to configure `connectedInstrumentTest` to include/exclude tests with/without an annotation?

Something similar to

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e annotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

Similarly, is it possible to specify a list of tests to be executed? Equivalent to

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.android.foo.FooTest,com.android.foo.TooTest com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```